# Why no precision loss with decimal arithmetic using IE10?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, numbers, decimal

I found there is no precision loss with IE10, which is common in other browsers like Edge, Chrome, Firefox. I'd like to know about is there any compatible workaround in IE10?

- In IE10

  [image]
- In other browsers

  [image]

Comment: Sounds like IE10 is not compliant with the official specification (not surprising by itself!)

Comment: I would like to know that JS engine of IE 10  (Chakra) uses the IEEE 754 floating-point format for number representation? If IEEE 754 is used then they should give a response like all other browser engines like V8.

Comment: The console might just be rounding off the number to fewer decimal places than other browsers. What do you see if you do `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3`?

Comment: @Barmar Good, return `false` when input `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3`. it is just a browser console tricky. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the browser data (cache and history), then recheck it.

I have tested it on my machine, all of the browsers (include IE 9+, Microsoft Edge, Chrome and Firefox) will display the same result `0.30000000000000004`, this is a Floating-Point Arithmetic issue, you could check [this article](https://floating-point-gui.de/) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript).

To solve the floating point arithmetic issue, we could use the following methods:

1. please refer to the following code:

   ```
   var x = 0.2 + 0.1;
   document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "0.2 + 0.1 = " + x;
   var y = (0.2*10 + 0.1*10) / 10;
   document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "0.2 + 0.1 = " + y;
   ```

   The output as below:

   ```
   0.2 + 0.1 = 0.30000000000000004
   0.2 + 0.1 = 0.3
   ```
2. using the toFixed method.

   ```
   var x = 0.1;
   var y = 0.2; 
   console.log((x + y).toFixed(1));
   ```

   The result is : `0.3`

Comment: IE version: 10.0.9200.17457;
IE update version: 10.0.30 (KB3078071);
 
This version could reproduce it.

Comment: The output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsxWa.png). Try to use (x + y).toFixed(18). If still not working, try to reset the browser setting or reinstall the browser, besides, you could also try to upgrade the IE browser version to the latest version.